# CSSTransitionGroup replacing

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to make it so that the client can see a sliding in and out whenever a content is **replaced** on the DOM. It will just switch out the src of the image inside of the CSSTransitionGroup.

```
            <CSSTransitionGroup
                component='div'
                className='image-container'
                transitionName='slide-in'
                transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
            >
                {this.props.name?<img src={this.state.img}/>:null}
            </CSSTransitionGroup>
```

Since the img is not being *removed* once it's mounted, the Leave action does not seem to fire. What's the approach into making it so that the Leave fires on an element replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you deduced, the inner element(s) of a CSSTransitionGroup need to be mounted or unmounted in order for it to work. It's not sufficient to simply change a property on the element(s).

Fortunately, there is a neat trick you can use that doesn't involve actually mounting or unmounting your inner components. CSSTransitionGroup uses the `key` property to identify elements and determine when they need to be cloned and/or animated. `key` should be a unique identifying string of some sort, and if that `key` string changes, then as far as CSSTransitionGroup is concerned you have just unmounted a component.

Try this:

```
        <CSSTransitionGroup
            component='div'
            className='image-container'
            transitionName='slide-in'
            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
        >
            {this.props.name?<img key={this.state.img} src={this.state.img}/>:null}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
```

Now when `this.state.img` changes, it should change the `key` property and trigger an animation.

Note: You should ALWAYS use the `key` prop on the elements inside of CSSTransitionGroup, even when you're not using this "trick". CSSTransitionGroup needs that prop on its children in order to function correctly.

[From the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html):

> You must provide the key attribute for all children of ReactCSSTransitionGroup, even when only rendering a single item. This is how React will determine which children have entered, left, or stayed.

Comment: Ah, I completely read past that without giving it second thought. Thank you so much!